# Codeigniter controller htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, routes, seo

Question: How do I move from an old url to a seo friendly url in codeigniter?

Example: 
I have a codeigniter controller called library.
The URL looks like www.domain.com/library

This is not seo friendly and I want it to look like www.domain.com/keyword-library
How do I fix this? .htaccess and routing isn't enough because I need the old pages to redirect to the new url with 301 so searchengines pick this up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the application/config/routes.php to reroute new url queries to the old controller object

```
$route['keyword-library/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "library/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5"; 
$route['keyword-library/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "library/$1/$2/$3/$4"; 
$route['keyword-library/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "library/$1/$2/$3"; 
$route['keyword-library/(:any)/(:any)'] = "library/$1/$2"; 
$route['keyword-library/(:any)'] = "library/$1"; 
$route['keyword-library'] = "library";
```

Then in the /index.php file before any other code executes I add this to reroute old pages to new pages.

```
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if(strpos($uri,'/library') === 0)
    {
    $expl = explode('/library',$uri);   
    //array_shift($expl);
    $query = implode('',$expl);
    $redirect= "https://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/orthomoleculaire-bibliotheek'.$query;
    header( "Status: 301 Moved Permanently" );
    header("Location: $redirect");
    exit(0);
    }
```

I have tried using .htaccess for this, but for some reason I didn't manage to make this work to reroute old urls to new urls with 301 because of the changing variables and variable lengths.

If anyone knows a more elegant solution, please post it, because I haven't been able to find one.

Comment: Yes, instead of using Htaccess, it would be better to go through route configuration.

Comment: Why not just do `$route['keyword-library/?'] = 'library'` and `$route['keyword-library/(.*)'] = 'library/$1'` instead of that approach?

Comment: @KusH as you can see I am using the route configuration. The problem is that it doesn't solve the redirect 301 problem for searchengines. It just makes an alias of the existing page. And google hates double content.

Comment: @RobinCastlin Ha, because that approach wasn't in the documentation of codeigniter routing... it only showed the $1 approach.